# Mikogo: Can't communicate with server

Tags: networking, remote-access

I am using the software 'Mikogo' which provides screen-sharing, I am trying to screen-share with a client so I can set up his email in outlook, he keeps saying that whenever he types in the session_ID and presses join session (that I started) he get's the error message 'can't communicate with server' after a few seconds. I am ADAMANT that this is because of his internet connection, but he doesn't seem to think so, is there any other reason I could connect to the Mikogo server and start a session, but he can't connect to the server with my session_ID? There isn't much in the way of Mikogo documentation so I'm not specifically sure what problem can rise that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mikogo Support here!

It does sound like this has something to do with your client's internet connection/firewall configuration. Please have them make sure that in the settings tab, "Automatically detect settings" is selected in the last section, "Proxy Information". If your client is working from within a company, it's possible that the company firewall is blocking Mikogo - in that case, their IT would need to whitelist Mikogo before he can connect.

It definitely doesn't have anything to do with your session ID - if that were the case, the error message would be more specific ("Invalid Session ID").

If you have any further inquiries, feel free to contact us directly at support-at-mikogo-dot-com. We're looking forward to hearing from you!

Best,
Annika
Mikogo Team